How to handle a Bitbucket file that is required in multiple places
I have a series of python files that are as follows,

Engineering files, used only by engineering for product development.

Production files, used by production for actually making and testing the products

Main.py, the main math module that contains a large hexapod class that does all the under the hood mathematical calculations required by both the Engineering files and Production files.


I currently have all the files in one bit bucket repository. This is undesirable because when production clones the repository they get all the engineering files which they do not need and should not really have access to.
How should the files be organized/distributed such that the following requirements are met?
Requirements:

Main.py has to be useable by both the engineering files and production files

There can only be 1 official version of Main.py. All updates to Main.py will occur in 1 place and affect both the production and engineering files that reference it.

Productions environment will only contain the production files and Main.py and must not include the engineering files

The engineering environment must at least contain the engineering files and these must work and correctly pull the required info from Main.py. The engineering environment may or may not contain Main.py and the production files

Main must be easily updated by production whenever we release a new version.


I have tried having two folders inside the repository Engineering and Production and only include Main in the production folder but now when I try and run the Engineering files they cannot find Main
I do not want to include the file path to Main in every production file as there are a bunch of files that all use Main and this could get messy to keep track of. I do not think that git submodules are a good solution as they are tied to a specific commit and I want something that will enable the production files to use the latest version of Main whenever I push that.
How do other companies handle code distribution to production employees/technicians? My company is new to using python for production code. I am a mechanical engineer so I am not really sure where to start.

I mean, they would still need to pull your latest changes... Submodules could work with an added step that you will go and make pull requests in the two project to update to the latest commit
